# What does Robotium mean by "index"?

Tags: android, integration-testing, robotium

I haven't been able to find any detailed documentation anywhere about what Robotium means by the "index" of a view, eg. `solo.clickOnButton(int index)`. From what I have found, it sounds like it's different than the view's id (as in `R.id.view_id`). I get the impression the index might be assigned based on "the order the views appear on the screen", but that's not very precise. What if multiple views appear beside each other? Are indices assigned depth-first or breadth-first in Linear Layouts? Top to bottom or bottom to top? Right to left or left to right? What about relative layouts? What if the views move to a new position? What if they overlap? It just doesn't seem to be a very precise notion. Can you explain to me what Robotium means by "index"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `public void clickOnButton(String text) {.....}`method, "text" is the text displayed by the button. e.g. for one button with "Sign In" text on it, you will have to use solo.clickOnButton("Sign In");

For `public void clickOnImageButton(int index) {......}`method, index is the index of the imageButton to click. Index of the image Button is increased from left to right starts at 0. i.e. if you have four image buttons in a row `"a", "b", "c"` and `"d"`, index for `a` will be `0`, for `b` it will be `1` and so on.
Use `solo.clickOnImageButton(0);` to click on button `"a"`

Edit:
Also index is increases from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks. That's less than optimal - it doesn't seem very precise, as per my comment. I hope they fix that in the future.